# Server Sent Events with Pyramid - How to detect if the connection to the client has been lost

Tags: pyramid, server-sent-events

I have a pyramid application that send SSE messages. It works basically like these:

```
def message_generator():
    for i in range(100):
        print("Sending message:" + str(i))
        yield "data: %s\n\n" % json.dumps({'message': str(i)})
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 10))

@view_config(route_name='events')
def events(request):
    headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream'),
               ('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')]
    response = Response(headerlist=headers)
    response.app_iter = message_generator()
    return response
```

When I browse to /events I get the events. When I move to another page the events stop, when I close the browser the events stop.

**The problem happens for example if I am in /events and I switch off the computer**. The server does not know that the client got lost and  message_generator keeps sending messages to the void.

In this page: [A Look at Server-Sent Events](https://medium.com/conectric-networks/a-look-at-server-sent-events-54a77f8d6ff7) mention this:

> ...the server should detect this (when the client stops) and stop
>   sending further events as the client is no longer listening for them.
>   If the server does not do this, then it will essentially be sending
>   events out into a void.

Is there a way to detect this with Pyramid? I tried with

```
request.add_finished_callback()
```

but this callback seems to be called with

```
return response
```

I use Gunicorn with gevent to start the server.

Any idea is highly appreciated

Comment: Perhaps something in the [pyramid_debugtoolbar](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_debugtoolbar/search?q=sse&unscoped_q=sse) would be of use?

Comment: Hi Steve. For I can see the code (line 189) don't use app_iter thus the connection does not keep alive with the client. The client in toolbar.js lines 108 and 109 will connect again and again and again creating a polling. If I understand correctly the advantage of SSE is the there is one active connection kept alive so the server send data, but the code doesn't seem to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PEP 3333:

> Applications returning a generator or other custom iterator should not assume the entire iterator will be consumed, as it may be closed early by the server.

Basically a WSGI server "should" invoke the `close()` method on the `app_iter` when a client disconnects (all generators, such as in your example, support this automatically). However, a server is not required to do it, and it seems many WSGI servers do not. For example, you mentioned gunicorn (which I haven't independently verified), but I did verify that waitress also does not. I opened [1] on waitress as a result, and have been working on a fix. Streaming responses in WSGI environments is shaky at best and usually depends on the server. For example, on waitress, you need to set `send_bytes=0` to avoid it buffering the response data.

[1] https://github.com/Pylons/waitress/issues/236

Comment: As an update, waitress now properly closes the socket in 1.3.0b0. So your example code will work unchanged. If you wish you can catch the `GeneratorExit` exception and do cleanup there when it exits early. It also doesn't require the send_bytes hack anylonger.